# Android Display via HDMI

Tags: android, hdmi

I have a client that's asking for an app that can play videos from a tablet to connected HDMI screens. I'd like to know if it's possible to show different output on the HDMI screen than the tablet itself? This is because I want to add a menu (layer on top of the tablet screen) that is accessible by the client and is not visible to the people seeing the TV Screen.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is possible since Android 4.2, see the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html) which also contain code samples:

> Android now allows your app to display unique content on additional
>   screens that are connected to the user’s device over either a wired
>   connection or Wi-Fi. To create unique content for a secondary display,
>   extend the Presentation class and implement the onCreate() callback.
>   Within onCreate(), specify your UI for the secondary display by
>   calling setContentView(). As an extension of the Dialog class, the
>   Presentation class provides the region in which your app can display a
>   unique UI on the secondary display.

The [Presentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html) Class in the SDK contains a code sample how to play a video and show some information at the same time on a second screen.

Comment: Thanks, my bad I forgot to add that this will be build using Cordova. Do you have any idea(s) if there is a plugin available? I'm trying to search but did not find anything yet.